# Retrieve the data from three different tables based two parameters in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is what i tried :

```
SELECT  A.cs_id, 
        A.class, 
        B.sec_id, 
        B.cs_id, 
        B.cs_name,
        C.stud_id,
        C.stud_class, 
        C.stud_section,
        C.stud_adm_no, 
        C.stud_full_name 
FROM class_section AS A  
INNER JOIN section_name as B ON A.cs_id=b.cs_id 
INNER JOIN student_detail as c ON C.stud_class=B.sec_id WHERE A.cs_id=1
```

It's retrieving the higher order variable only

Comment: please provide some details, so vague

Comment: I think `.stud_mother_name` should be `C.stud_mother_name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
A.cs_id, 
A.class, 
B.sec_id,
B.cs_name,
C.stud_id,
C.stud_class, 
C.stud_section,
C.stud_adm_no, 
C.stud_full_name 
FROM class_section AS A  
INNER JOIN section_name as B ON A.cs_id=B.cs_id 
INNER JOIN student_detail as C ON C.stud_class=B.sec_id WHERE A.cs_id=1
```

May be your alias problem `b` should be `B` `c` should be `C`